Laravel Reverb (AWS) connect to Nuxt3 (cloudflare)
I’m a little in over my head. Previously I had a Laravel/Vue.js server and pusher.js  was working fine.
Then I switched over to Nuxt3 frontend with Laravel 11 / reverb as the backend. Since the two servers are separated, it’s not so clear.
In my nuxt file .vue
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

onMounted(async () => {
   
   window.Echo.channel("update-item").listen("ItemEvent", ({ item: newItem }) => {
   console.log('success');
   if (item.value.id == newItem.id) {
       console.log('success x2');
       item.value = newItem;
      }
   });
   
    
   });

Channel.php looks like this
Broadcast::channel('update-item', ['item' => '456']);

I built a nuxt plugin based off of this SO
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Pusher: any;
    Echo: any;
  }
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  window.Pusher = Pusher
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'us2',
    forceTLS: false,
  });
})


I started the reverb, and it is working.
I can see web socket go out, and I get ping, but I don't seem to be getting any data?
I running out or errors, to track down.

This issue was so annoying and confusing, I got out of the coding business!

I had a fair amount of issues getting Laravel Reverb working with Cloudflare and AWS so I thought I would share how I fixed the issue. It sounds like the connections have been made but nothing is catching your events (same issues I had)
Things to check to fix the issue.
What port are you running the connection on? From looking at the comments on this thread you are running on port 8080 which is NOT supported over HTTPS. Read more here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/network-ports/
Did you check you can curl? curl -v https://example.com:2053
On the AWS side, things get a little complex. I managed to get everything working by creating a Target Group with the protocol for my websocket port 2053, which I then assigned as a listener inside my Load Balancer.
You will also need to add a rule for your listener that handles http traffic. In my case port 443. The rule is setup to catch traffic from /app/* because the WebSocket initially establishes the connection on port 443 before it gets translated to port 2053. When Reverb creates the connection, it uses the /app/{websocketid} endpoint to establish that connection.
Make sure you have the correct configuration in your ECS task definition, especially with the port mappings:
"portMappings": [
    {
       "name": "my-app-2053-tcp",
       "containerPort": 2053,
       "hostPort": 2053,
       "protocol": "tcp"
    },
]

Finally, remember to start Reverb inside your ECS along with your queue! you can just set QUEUE_CONNECTION to sync.
I would highly reccomend setting this up with supervisor as it tends to stop and not restart!
[program:laravel-websocket-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan reverb:start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stopwaitsecs=3600

Hope this helps.

Since this can't fit into the comment section, I decided to write it as an answer.
Here are a few things you can try:
First of all, the broadcaster option within the call to new Echo() should be reverb, while it's pusher in your case. Here's an example of a proper initialization of the Echo client:
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

Also, notice that we don't have a cluster option here, it's unused in Reverb.
Another thing you may want to look at is the configuration of your AWS firewall. By default, Laravel Reverb runs on port 8080, so you need to make sure that this port has an AWS outbound rule.
By default, broadcast messages sit in a queue, and a background job reads messages from this queue and tries to run them, so I suggest you set the QUEUE_CONNECTION variable of your .env to be sync so that you're basically disabling queueing behavior. This is just temporary to help you debug the exact issue.

Thanks for your response.  1. allowed port 8080, prior to this question. 2. window.Echo function: Keep in mind the nuxt3 is on a cloudflare server, the Laravel/Reverb server is on AWS, so import.meta won't work, because it's going server to server, similar to an API call. Here is a link to page in question. In the inspector, network/WS you can see the initial ping to the laravel. https://auctionbro.net/items/pinnacle-of-pkmn-cards-charizard-bgs-7-5-nm-mt-plus-1st-ed-thick-stamp-shadowless-base-set-pokemon-ca

@Chad no problem, in this case you can just hard-code the values instead of using the import.meta object. In the link you've sent, I see that Echo is connecting to a pusher cluster, and not Laravel Reverb

I made the changes, but it looks like Echo needs pusher-js as dependence. I'm not sure if Reverb was meant to handle this?

@Chad This is absolutely normal, don't worry about it. Echo needs pusher-js as a dependency because Reverb uses the Pusher protocol for WebSocket subscriptions and messaging, but this doesn't necessarily mean that you will use Pusher.
You can check this link if you want: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/broadcasting#client-reverb

It's bizarre because "ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined" breaks the webpage.

@Chad Yes, you need to install both pusher-js an laravel-echo and use them inside the JS bundle. npm install --save-dev laravel-echo pusher-js
